# Display lines not beginning with one or more letters and not ending with one or more digits

Tags: grep

I am attempting to display lines that do NOT begin with one or more letters and do NOT end in one or more digits - using grep.

What I have so far is

```
grep '^[^a-zA-Z]'
```

This shows me all the lines that do not start with a letter, so `a`, `abc` do not show BUT `abc` (has a leading space) is shown, correctly, for example.

I am not sure how to include the second portion of this which is *NOT end in one or more digits*.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why not:

```
^[^a-zA-Z].*[^0-9]$
```

Note that this doesn't cover the case when only one character is present.

Comment: I ended up using  '^[^a-zA-Z].*[^0-9]$' and that seems to provide me with what looks like the results I should expect